# Cannot install nvdia-173 ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I tried to pick the driver from additional drivers but i cant enable it. Found [this article](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=102602) to downgrade xorg. I created a pin file in /etc/apt/preferences.d. When i tried to downgrade i got this

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-173 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                   xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way to install this driver or should i go back to 12.04 with unity 2d?

Comment: Nvidia-173 should be installable with the original kernel (3.13) and xorg (1.15.1) in place. If you've installed hardware enablement stacks, which upgrade both xorg and kernel, nvidia-173 installation is not going to work. I am not sure how to revert to the original packages, other then doing a clean install with the [14.04.1 iso](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.2/). Also, you may want to add the created files for review.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to install 14.04.1 and will write back.

Comment: You were right. I managed to install nvidia drivers with 14.04.1. The problem now is that when i log in i just have a black screen with a mouse cursor.

Comment: Perhaps Ubuntu/Unity is not the best choice for an old Nvidia graphics card. Unity is known to be too much for cards older then Geforce 8000. You could try the same version of [Xubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/), or edit the question, and add the relevant info. Then we can try to help.

Comment: Nevermind i will keep 12.04. Thanks again for the help